# HTML5 doctype with RDFa

Tags: 7, theming, rdf

I'm using Omega 3, and have a redundant HTML doctype header line.

How do I correct this so I have my HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` line, and specify RDFa?

Currently, the first two lines of my pages are:

```html
<DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML+RDFa 1.1//EN">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" version="HTML+RDFa 1.1"...>
```

Comment: As far as I remember you need to override the html.tpl.php in your theme directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omega4 supports

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>
```

where you don't have to manually define RDFa.

Beside Omega4 I normally do (usually I use Zen, but you can do this in other themes too):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="dc: http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
```

and define `property="http://purl.org/dc/terms/TERMS` wherever I use RDFa

Dublincore Metadata Initiative has detailed information about the [terms](http://dublincore.org/documents/2012/06/14/dcmi-terms/)

Drupal7 core has RDF support via `rdf_namespaces`. The hook implementation is:

```
function hook_rdf_namespaces() {
  return array(
    'content' => 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/',
    'dc' => 'http://purl.org/dc/terms/',
    'foaf' => 'http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/',
    'og' => 'http://ogp.me/ns#',
    'rdfs' => 'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#',
    'sioc' => 'http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#',
    'sioct' => 'http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#',
    'skos' => 'http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#',
    'xsd' => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#',
  );
}
```

so you can simple do `<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>` in your **html.tpl.php** file where you start `<html>`.

If you want latest RDF support there is a module for that one too called [RDFX](https://drupal.org/project/rdfx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with Omega, specifically, but many themes take their doctype expressions right out of the variables array when the theme templates are run.  I would recommend undoing whatever you did that has caused the double-doctype issue and consider changing gears.

In your theme/sub-theme's template.php, add some code to your hook_preprocess_html().

According to as recently as April 2013, this code snippet appeared to work for an Omega user (see: https://groups.drupal.org/node/295068#comment-916713)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 **/
function YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $vars['doctype'] = '<!DOCTYPE html>' . "\n";
  $vars['rdf'] = new stdClass;
  $vars['rdf']->version = '';
  $vars['rdf']->namespaces = '';
  $vars['rdf']->profile = '';

  // Serialize RDF Namespaces into an RDFa 1.1 prefix attribute.
  if ($vars['rdf_namespaces']) {
    $prefixes = array();
    foreach (explode("\n  ", ltrim($vars['rdf_namespaces'])) as $namespace) {
      // Remove xlmns: and ending quote and fix prefix formatting.
      $prefixes[] = str_replace('="', ': ', substr($namespace, 6, -1));
    }
    $vars['rdf']->namespaces = ' prefix="' . implode(' ', $prefixes) . '"';
  }
}
```